# SQL - Select all skills

Tags: sql

it's been a while since I used SQL so I'm asking sorry if it's too easy.
I have to select all the skills that a user has, so I have three tables.

```
User (id, name)
Skills (id, name)
User_skills (id_user, id_skill)
```

If the `user1` has 2 skills; for example *Hibernate* (id `1`) and *Java* (id `2`)
and the `user2` has 1 skill; *Java* (id `1`)
Passing `1` and `2`, I want to retrieve users that have both.

With the IN() function I get all the users that have at least one of the skills, but I want to filter them out!
Thanks to all in advance

Comment: What flavor of RDBMS are you using?

Comment: at first, i thought this was going to be a question about having skills with regards to `select *`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If one skill can only be assigned exactly once to a user (i.e. (id_user, id_skill) is the PK for the user_skills table), then the following will do what you want:

```
SELECT id_user
FROM user_skills
WHERE id_skill IN (1,2)
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. I normally chuck this link in as well http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 3):

Join to the association table `user_skills` twice, putting the skill ID in the `on` clause of each join:

```
select u.*
from user u
join user_skills us1 on us1.id_user = u.id and us1.id_skill = 1
join user_skills us2 on us2.id_user = u.id and us2.id_skill = 2
```

By using `join` (and not `left join`) this query requires the user have *both* skills

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM user as u
WHERE 
  EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM User_skills WHERE id_user=u.id AND id_skill=1 )
  AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM User_skills WHERE id_user=u.id AND id_skill=2 )
```